# How could I fix this warning?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

> ```
> SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Sep 20 13:08:07 2018
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle. All rights reserved.
>
> Enter user-name: system
> Enter password:
> ERROR:
> ORA-28002: the password will expire within 4 days
> ```

Every time I login into my database it shows this warning message of password gonna expire in .. days. Now its just 4 days left I don't know what to do to fix this warning.

Comment: I assume that you are asking here because you've already tried changing your password?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `password` command after logging in to change your password:

```
SQL> password
Changing password for SYSTEM
Old password:
New password:
Retype new password:
Password changed
SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

The SYS account is in a Profile that enforces password expiration.
There are two ways of tackling this.

The first is just to deal with it and change the password when[ever] it expires, making sure that you store the new password somewhere safe so that your fellow DBAs can find it.  If you're running Data Guard and OEM insists on connecting as SYS instead of DBSNMP to manage it, you also have to update the password in OEM, which is a Royal pain.

The alternative is to prevent the password from expiring at all.  To do so, you need to reconfigure the Profile that the SYS account belongs to, or create a new profile with the necessary properties:

```
select username, profile 
from dba_users 
where username = 'SYS' ; 

USERNAME  PROFILE 
--------  -------
SYS       ETERNAL

select profile, limit 
from dba_profiles 
where resource_name = 'PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME' ; 

PROFILE  LIMIT
-------  -----
DEFAULT  90
ETERNAL  UNLIMITED
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to do that as a privileged user (SYS probably being the most popular whose privileges are abused), you can change password for any other user using `ALTER USER` command, such as

```
SQL> show user
USER is "KCDBA"
SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;

User altered.

SQL>
```

Saying that SYS is abused means that you should avoid using it. Instead, create a new privileged user (as KCDBA in my example), grant it DBA role and let it perform DBA tasks. Leave SYS (and SYSTEM and similar Oracle-owned users) alone.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

You should not be logging in as `SYSTEM` in the first place.

Assign someone the `DBA` role, but not as a `DEFAULT` role.  This way, the DBA (person) has to enable the role using his/her account .  This gives you the ability to `AUDIT` who logged in to do something and what he/she did.

If you want, you can even add a password to the `ROLE`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Oracle. You can run below mentioned command to change the password:

```
alter user SYSTEM
identified by **password**
```

You can run this command after successfully logging in to oracle database

Answer (score 0):

The ORA-28002 warning is issued when an account is in the password grace period. The password is about to expire and must be changed within PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME days before it definitely expires.

**To find an account's last password change time, issue the following SQL statements from a DBA connection:**

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
SQL> SELECT PTIME FROM SYS.USER$ WHERE NAME = 'username';
```

**The account creation time can be obtained using:**

```
SQL> SELECT CREATED FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'username';
```

We can resolve this issue using 2 ways:
**1. You may back out of the change made to the PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME limit by executing:**

```
SQL> ALTER PROFILE test LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
```

**2. Reset the password by login to sqlplus.**

```
SQL> alter user USERNAME identified by **password**;
```

**NOTE:**

This change only affects accounts who have not entered their grace period (and started getting ORA-28002 on connection). Accounts that have entered their grace period will have to change their passwords. It is possible to alter the users and set the passwords to the current values.  The following script can be used for this:

```
connect / as sysdba

spool runme.sql

set serveroutput on size 200000

declare
    stmt varchar2(200);
    v_old_hash user$.password%type;
    v_new_hash user$.spare4%type;
    v_hash varchar2(200);
begin
   for user_rec in (select name, password, spare4 from user$ where type#=1 and astatus in(1,2)) loop
      v_old_hash := user_rec.password;
      v_new_hash := user_rec.spare4;
      if not ((v_old_hash is null) and (v_new_hash is null)) then
         if (v_new_hash is null) then
             if v_old_hash <> 'EXTERNAL' then
                 v_hash := ''''||v_old_hash||'''';
             else
             goto end_loop;
         end if;
      end if;
      if (v_old_hash is null) then
          v_hash := ''''||v_new_hash||'''';
      end if;
      if ((v_old_hash is not null) and (v_new_hash is not null)) then
          v_hash := ''''||v_old_hash||';'||v_new_hash||'''';
      end if;
          stmt := 'alter user '||user_rec.name||' identified by values'||v_hash;
      end if;
     dbms_output.put_line(stmt||';');
  <<end_loop>>
  null;
  end loop;
end;
/

spool off
```